# Write from SQL Server CE table to excel file

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sql-server-ce

Sorry for my spelling, I create so C# form application with local database. I created simple code which worked fine:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = 4.sdf");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xls = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook vb = xls.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet vs = (Worksheet)xls.ActiveSheet;
String t = "SELECT d.[regnr], d.[dalisid],d.[kiekis],d.[kaina] FROM [bilietas] AS b, [dalispard] AS d WHERE b.[regnr]=d.[regnr]";
                    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(t, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int i=2;
                    object aa, bb, cc, dd;
                    vs.Cells[1, 1] = "Reg. NR.";
                    vs.Cells[1, 2] = "Dalies ID";
                    vs.Cells[1, 3] = "Kiekis";
                    vs.Cells[1, 4] = "Kaina";
                    try
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            aa = rdr.GetValue(0);
                            bb = rdr.GetValue(1);
                            cc = rdr.GetValue(2);
                            dd = rdr.GetValue(3);


                            vs.Cells[i, 1] = aa.ToString();
                            vs.Cells[i, 2] = bb.ToString();
                            vs.Cells[i, 3] = cc.ToString();
                            vs.Cells[i, 4] = dd.ToString();

                            i++;
                        }
                    }


  finally { conn.Close(); rdr.Close(); }
            xls.Visible = true;
```

it bugged and started write emty cells on excel file when I edited input button for refreshing datagridview when input to table are saved by adding:

```
string eilute = "SELECT * FROM bilietas";
            SqlCeCommand cmdd = new SqlCeCommand(eilute, conn);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                dt.Load(cmdd.ExecuteReader());
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dt;
                bilietasDataGridView.DataSource = bs;

                MessageBox.Show("Atlikta", "Atlikta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            finally { conn.Close(); }
```

So I really have no idea why it not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel interop is not the best idea in your case - it is slow and requires Excel installed. Try other approach - *OleDbConnection* way. You can write data to Excel worksheet using plain SQL INSERT command. Create *OleDbConnection* object with the following connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=SAMPLE.XLSX;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML\";"
```

After that create new *OleDbCommand* with text like this:

```
"insert into [YOR_WORKBOOK_NAME$] ([COLUMN_NAME]) values ('Sample text')"
```

Execute command with *ExecuteNonQuery* method. Repeat this command with different values to insert many rows to your workbook. This method is much faster than interop approach.